# Reportviewer Error

Tags: vb.net, report, reportviewer

I am using VB.NET and MySql and created a report, the report is working without any error on developer machine. It gives following error when I installed it and running on another machine. I have included Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
[image: Reoprtviewer]

This is my code for loading report

```
Private Sub frmRptCustomerBal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim cn As New dbConnection
        cn.connect()
        rptCustomerBalTableAdapter.Connection = cn.conn
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "rptCustomerBal.rdlc"
        Me.rptCustomerBalTableAdapter.Fill(Me.rptCustomerBal._rptCustomerBal)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        cn.close_conn()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please how did you solved your error. Am having the same which is making surrendered. I will gratefull.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't installed Report Viewer on the client system.
Here is the [download link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/B/7/FB728406-A1EE-4AB5-9C56-74EB8BDDF2FF/ReportViewer.msi) for Report Viewer.